# Installing fonts with PowerShell commands in all users in windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, fonts, users

I want to make an unattended Windows 10 x64 LTSC (1809). I've installed a number of fonts with Powershell via the Powershell script in the following repository:
[here](https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/0088b07de8951403a643a8485af2709b)

[image]

That worked fine, but that work just in the current user. when I trying to create a new user, I can't see my new fonts.
New fonts are only installed on the current user. But I want them to be installed on all users.

Windows had two option to install fonts in current user Or all users:
[image]

I think this script just install fonts in current user and should be had a command to install in all users.
This is my Power-Shell Command:

```
$SourceDir   = "InstallFont\"
$Source      = "InstallFont\*"
$Destination = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace(0x14)
$TempFolder  = "C:\Windows\Temp\Fonts"


New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $SourceDir

New-Item $TempFolder -Type Directory -Force | Out-Null

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include '*.ttf','*.ttc','*.otf' -Recurse | ForEach {
    If (-not(Test-Path "C:\Windows\Fonts\$($_.Name)")) {

        $Font = "$TempFolder\$($_.Name)"
        
        # Copy font to local temporary folder
        Copy-Item $($_.FullName) -Destination $TempFolder
        
        # Install font
        $Destination.CopyHere($Font,0x10)

        # Delete temporary copy of font
        Remove-Item $Font -Force
    }
}
```

So how will change this code or is there a way to install new fonts in all users in PowerShell.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @somebadhat . Can you help me?

Comment: The solution is here : https://jordanmalcolm.com/deploying-windows-10-fonts-at-scale/
Just copy the font and insert the needed line in the registry.

For the registry part, I installed the font and exported what I found in HKLM. I now have a .reg file I can import with "regedit /s file.reg"